# Localized strings in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, localization

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30442/how-to-find-the-localized-name-of-the-web-part-gallery) I got the tip to use `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString` to get the localized title of a list. Now I want to use this way in a Silverlight app.

However, there is no SPUtility to find for silverlight. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is not possible in Silverlight. I used a Webservice to work around this.